# Using parenthesis for decimals with exponents

Tags: notation

Should we add parenthesis to decimal numbers when raised to an exponent as the following:
$$(0.26)^2$$
or we don't need to, so it should be displayed as:
$$0.26^2$$

I always used the parenthesis in such cases for the following situations only:

1-When there is an operator ($\times$, $\div$, $+$, or $-$) or more between numbers/variables like $(3+1)^2$, $(2\times y)^2$, and $(3+2i)^2$

2-When there is a negative sign like $(-x)^2$ and $(-3)^3$

3-When there are more than one variable or a combination of variables and numbers like $(2x)^2$, $(xy)^2$, and $(2xz)^4$

I prefer not to add parenthesis when there is no need to, but I am not sure which format is the right one.

Comment: Adding parentheses is always good...It clarifies the meaning easily

Comment: Both are fine: Just be sure not to use them inappropriately. For example: $$(-2)^2 \neq -2^2$$

Comment: Unless the decimal point $.$ becomes a $\cdot$ (`\cdot`), there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of exponents as "functions that act on the previous single object".
For example, $1-3^2 = -8$. Without any brackets, "$3$" is the first single object you come across. With brackets, $(1-3)^2 = 4$. Now the "$3$" isn't a standalone object, it's part of a bigger single object, $(1-3)$. Now let's think about decimals. $5.4^2 = 29.16$, and there's no ambiguity. This is because the "$4$" on the end isn't a standalone object, it's just a part of the entire number, $5.4$. With decimals there is no need for parentheses.